Can I forward stdout / stderr from an attached process to lldb's console?
Consider the program:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void example() {
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
}

int main() {
    sleep(1);
    sleep(1);
    sleep(1);
}

The sleep(1) usages here just give us an opportunity to attach a debugger. We'll compile and run it with:
clang test.c -o test; ./test

Then, in a separate terminal, we'll attach to that process with:
lldb -p $(pgrep -nx test)

From lldb, we can evaluate expressions using expr; for example, we can run the example() function with:
expr (void) example()

However, the generated output is (understandably) written to the original program's console, rather than the lldb console.
Is there any way to capture or redirect stdout / stderr from the attached process back to lldb? Or will I need to redirect output from the test program to some known location, and read / stream output separately?
For posterity, the ultimate goal is to include some debugging utilities that could be called when interactively debugging via lldb -- sort of a poor-man's REPL for introspecting a debugged process.

Don't know if this helps, but, under linux, if I want a program to wait until it is attached by a debugger, I loop and parse /proc/self/status and wait for TracerPid: to become non-zero. And/or I loop on a volatile global variable (e.g.) volatile int running_under_debugger = 0; and wait for it to become non-zero. (i.e. after attaching, use lldb to set this variable).

With further cooperation, the debugger could poke certain globals in the program that tell it to redirect its output. (e.g. put an output named pipe filename or PTY filename into a global char array). You could put the code to do the redirect into your example function.

We could accomplish this with a named pipe / fifo. The general idea is:

Provide some routines for redirecting stdout / stderr to some known file location;

Stream output from that file location (this can be done in the background from the same terminal where lldb is being run).


With this program:
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int saved_stdout;
int saved_stderr;

void begin_redirect() {

    // save stdout, stderr
    saved_stdout = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
    saved_stderr = dup(STDERR_FILENO);

    // redirect stdout, stderr to fifo
    int fd = open("/tmp/dbg-fifo", O_WRONLY);
    dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
    dup2(fd, STDERR_FILENO);
    close(fd);
}

void end_redirect() {
    dup2(saved_stdout, STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(saved_stdout);
    dup2(saved_stderr, STDERR_FILENO);
    close(saved_stderr);
}

void example() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
}

int main() {
    sleep(3);
    sleep(3);
}

We could then attach with lldb, and do the following:
tail -f /tmp/dbg-fifo &
lldb -p $(pgrep -nx test)

Then, in lldb, we can control when redirection happens, and effectively see stdout / stderr as it's produced. For example:
(lldb) expr (void) begin_redirect()
(lldb) expr (void) example()
Hello, world!

One could imagine further extending this by allowing some way to communicate the fifo name / location, wrapping the tail + lldb invocations into a single function, and so on.
